# Loading dat file as array of arrays

Tags: arrays, load, wolfram-mathematica

I am quiete new in Python and I have already problems to load data from dat file, my data originaly produced in mathematica are in for of array of arrays:

```
1AL1.dat = { {0.1, 0.2 ... 0.6}, {0.2, 0.6, ...}, ...}
```

My problem is when I load data in python with

```
import numpy as np
myarray = np.fromfile('1AL1.dat')
```

I will get flattened array

```
{0.1, 0.2 ... 0.6, 0.2, 0.6 ...}
```

How can I load and work with this mathematica produced data in form of array of arrays ?

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144770/exchanging-numpy-arrays-between-python-and-mathematica

Comment: that is a topic for oposite problem